# Filter hash by key and increase corresponding values

Tags: ruby

I have a hash: `date => integer`. I need to change the values, but only for keys, satisfying the requirement: `date1 < key < date2`. What is an elegant way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean? hash should be updated directly, not to return a new hash with updated values.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, just to know if you wanted a functional or imperative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
my_hash.each {|key, value| my_hash[key] += 1 if date1 < key and key < date2 }
```

Comment: That won't change `my_hash[key]`, it will change the local `value` within the block but that change won't be reflected in `my_hash`.

Comment: In my case it worked, cause I had Struct with integers inside and not just one integer :)

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is reduce over your hash. You will iterate through your hash and check each key, if it meets the conditions you will put that key into a new hash with a new value, modified however you would like. Otherwise, the key goes into the new hash with the old value.

```
hash.reduce({}) do |memo,iter| 
  if iter[0] < Time.now
    memo[iter[0]] = iter[1] + 1
  else 
    memo[iter[0]] = iter[1]
  end
  memo
end
```

What this says is iterate over the hash. When you iterate over the hash with a reduce, it passes each pair [key,value] to the block. Thus, iter[0] is the key, iter[1] the value. Now we test on the key, if the condition is satisfied change the value and put the key and new value into the new hash. Otherwise, put the key and old value into the hash. The modified new hash is returned for the next iteration of the reduce. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh it seems as I was writing this, the OP specified a mutable, non-functional solution was required. I apologize. Why is an inplace update needed?

Comment: It's ok for me too, thanks for spending time! I +1 your answer.

Comment: When iterating over a `Hash`, you should *really* consider using destructuring bind, it makes the code much more readable. The fact that you had to spend an entire two sentences on explaining this should be a hint: `hash.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, value)| ... end`

Comment: Great point. I always forget that Ruby can do destructuring like this.